# Is "腹違いの兄" considered a slur?

Tags: translation, slang

Is "腹違いの兄" currently considered a slur? What about with past generations in Japan? In US society at least it once had negative connotation. But, now there is no negative meaning at all. What about Japan?

What is the formal way to say "腹違いの兄"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The formal and neutral way of saying this is 異母【いぼ】兄弟【きょうだい】 or 母親の違う兄.

腹違い is slangy, but [not derogatory in itself in most cases](http://search.yomiuri.co.jp/komachi.html?q=%E8%85%B9%E9%81%95%E3%81%84&fq=all&term=ALL&ch=). Some people may feel it's politically incorrect or vulgar, and use the alternative expressions.